# Selenium django HTML functional test move to next input

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, selenium

Looking at:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=partial_link_text#module-selenium.webdriver.common.keys

it appear that you can move between input fields with those *Keys*, I've tried:

```
    elem = self.browser.find_element_by_id("base") # find first input field
    elem.send_keys("1234,5")           # compile data
    elem=elem.send_keys(Keys.TAB)      # move to next
    elem.send_keys("456,5")            # compile data
```

but this get an error, because elem=elem.send_keys(Keys.TAB) isn't the next input field.

How can I move to next input field and compile it, without recreate the element object with *find_element_by...*?

Comment: what happens if you manually click on the #base element, type in some text and then hit tab?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't do `without recreate the element object with find_element_by...`?

Comment: If I manually use the TAB key, it do the right thing: it goes to next input field. I'd prefer keep the test generic, if I change code maybe I wouldn't need to change the tests... eventually